# Getting Exception while creating kie container for drools

Tags: java, drools, kie, cookiecontainer

I am getting below exception while creating kie container for drools.

```
No implementation for org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem annotated with interface `org.eclipse.sisu.inject.TypeArguments$Implicit` was bound.


    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.LocatorWiring

1 error
    at 

    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:448)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:168)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:166)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:140)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.<init>(PlexusComponentProvider.java:37)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildComponentProvider(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:56)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:81)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:75)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.newMavenEmbedder(MavenProjectLoader.java:66)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:53)
    at org.kie.scanner.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:49)
    at org.kie.scanner.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:33)
    at org.drools.compiler.kproject.xml.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:455)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:432)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:134)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:169)
```

Answer (score 0):

This similar error happened to me when there was release ID missing in pom file. I think same thing could happen if pom file is missing in general. Could you give some code context? It's hard to see what is wrong only from the error output.
Do you have kmodule.xml file configured externally or you configure it in the code?